# Run-time Error 1004: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file

Tags: excel, vba

Getting above error in Title while trying to open the file in Macro to copy the data from that file to a central file(in which the macro is run). Checked the path and everything is fine. The Macro has opened and copied 10 files before the 11th instance of opening the file in the similar way however the error occurs on 11th file only. Tried changing position of the file access(by putting 12th file in sequence after 10th) however same error occurs.

Declared dr_x and fl_x as strings

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

dr_1 = "<path for the directory 1>"
Workbooks.Open (dr_1 & fl_1)
Windows("<file name 1.xlsx>").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("<Target File Name.xlsm>").Activate
Sheets("Tab_File1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Could we see the code in question please?  At the moment it could be lots of things - does the file exist?  Is it already open & locked elsewhere? Password protected? Does your code have an `Error.Raise` statement (no idea which number)?  Could be another 100 reasons why.... not all the above problems will raise that error, but sound like they might.  Does it sound like any of them?

Comment: Declared dr_x and fl_x as strings
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dr_1 = "<path for the directory 1>"
    Workbooks.Open (dr_1 & fl_1)
    Windows("<file name 1.xlsx>").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("<Target File Name.xlsm>").Activate
    Sheets("Tab_File1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: Error in title is occuring for 10th file

Comment: That code only opens one file.  I can't see how it can get an error on the 10th file?

Comment: I have declared around 20 dr_x variables as string and around 20 fl_x variables as string. Now when MACRO tries to open 11th file using above code , it displays error as unable to find the file

Comment: I'd say that's a major problem there - you have `Dim dr_1 AS String, dr_2 AS String,....`.  Lots of work - would be easier to cycle through an array or collection of file names, or just open all XLSX files in a certain folder.  How are the files stored?

Comment: Tried declaring the variables for individual copy-paste operations instead of declaring all at once in the beginning as the files are stored in different paths, however what I had observed is that after initial 10 reads(copy-pastes), the error occurs every time for 11th read(copy -paste) in whatever sequence I access

Comment: Perhaps the file you're trying to open is already open somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I got for the above issue is below -

```
Sub Consolidate()
Path = "\\Source-Path\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

where "\Source-Path\" is the folder where all source files(from where the data is to be copied) are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're doing, but removing all the `SELECT` & `ACTIVATE` statements makes the code run a lot smoother.

The `SourceFiles` array contains the paths to all the workbooks you want to open and copy from.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim TargetFile As Workbook, SourceFiles() As Variant
    Dim tgtLastCell As Range, srcLastCell As Range
    Dim tgtWrkSht As Worksheet, srcWrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim fle As Variant

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    SourceFiles = Array("C:\MyPath\Book1.xlsx", _
                        "C:\MyOtherPath\Book2.xlsx")

    Set TargetFile = ThisWorkbook 'If target sheet is in file containing this code.
    'or
    'Set TargetFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\SomePath\Book3.xlsx")

    Set tgtWrkSht = TargetFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each fle In SourceFiles
        'Find current last cell in target sheet.
        Set tgtLastCell = LastCell(tgtWrkSht)

        'Open source file, set reference to sheet1 and find the last cell containing data.
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(fle)
        Set srcWrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set srcLastCell = LastCell(srcWrkSht)

        'Copy & paste contents of sheet on to end of target sheet.
        With srcWrkSht
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), srcLastCell).Copy Destination:=tgtWrkSht.Cells(tgtLastCell.Row + 1, 1)
        End With

        'Close source workbook.
        wrkBk.Close False
    Next fle

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Darren - tried you code however gave the simiar error - Unable to open the file on first file.

Comment: Looking at the comment by @MacroMan and the solution you've posted you should only have to change `Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(fle)` to `Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(fle, TRUE)`.